# @DynamicInsert @DynamicUpdate does not work?

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 4.
When I use

```
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true, dynamicUpdate = true,
 selectBeforeUpdate = true)
```

it works.

But, I found that they have deprecated, so I follow the instructions to use the @DynamicInsert and @DynamicUpdate, like this:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@SelectBeforeUpdate 
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
       ..........
}
```

It does not work.

How do I use @DynamicInsert and @DynamicUpdate ?

Answer (score 5):

They are broken in the current released version (4.1.0 through 4.1.3).  The issue is https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7074

EDIT: updated the link to the current url.  This was fixed in hibernate 4.1.4

Comment: Link is not working.Will please elaborate issue in short.Is not not useful in hibernate 4.X

Comment: Fixed the link.  There's nothing to elaborate -- the problem was fixed in Hibernate 4.1.4 so just upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

@SelectBeforeUpdate - works in Hibernate 4.x since org.hibernate.annotations.Entity has been deprecated 
Note:  This is a replacement to the earlier org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(selectBeforeUpdate=true)