# How to avoid creating a new row if similar row exists?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, updates, hibernate-annotations

I need to configure hibernate to avoid creating duplicate rows, (although the row exists it creates a new one, and since only one filed is set it set all the rest to NULL)

Lets say I have a row as following

```
id des    index age
1  MyName 2     23
```

Although I just set MyName as des and it already exists in the Name table hibernate 
create a new row as following

```
id des    index age
1  MyName 2     23
2  MyName Null  Null     << new row with null values will be created 
                            rather than updating the previous one
```

When I want to sa
 .
So I have added the following annotation to my class but it crossed the Entity, and dynamicUpdate.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
  dynamicUpdate = true
)
```

I used `@DynamicUpdate` as well, although hibernate accept it but still I have the same problem.

Is there any other method to do it ? Version of my hibernate is as following

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
      <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

****Based on Ray's comment blew, By assigning a value to Id of child class it works properly but how about if I do not have the ID? do I have to do a select to find the id first ? Is there any method to force hibernate to do it automatically r based on values of child class rahter than doing a separate select to find the id? ****

**User.Java**

```
....
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user") 
@DynamicUpdate
public class User implements Serializable {

  private int ID;
  private Name name;
  private String type;

  public User() {
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  public int getID() {
     return ID;
  }

  public void setID(int ID) {
     this.ID = ID;
  }

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  public Name getName() {
     return name;
  }

  public void setName(Name name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  .....
```

**Name.Java**

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Name")
public class Name implements Serializable {

private int id;
private String des;
private String index;
private String age;

public Name() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id", unique= true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

.....
```

**Model.java**

```
public void addMyUsers(){
   Name name = new Name();
   name.setDes("MyName");
   While( ..... )
   {
       User user = new User();
       user.setName(name);
       user.setType(X);
       addUser(user);
   }
}

public void addUser(User user) {
        session = Util.getSession();

        session.beginTransaction();


        session.merge(user); 
        //session.saveOrUpdate(user);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8935975/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks I read that before that does not give a solution  just mentioned that these tags are deprecated.

Comment: Maybe you need to read answer of that question as well.

Comment: On 4.2.1 it is working, upgrade to latest if possible.

Comment: @AleksandrM so this is actually a duplicate.

Comment: @yair the answer of that question is wrong, as these tags are not deprecated. As no one is able to view that question I am opening a new question

Comment: @AleksandrM I have updated it to 4.2.1 but still does not update the previous row

Comment: It seems that you don't understand what `@DynamicUpdate` does. See this post: http://chekkal.blogspot.com/2012/09/hibernate-dynamic-updates.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM I suppose I have chosen a wrong title, I have updated the question, also provided an example

Comment: Use `saveOrUpdate` method and read documentation next time.

Comment: @AleksandrM I read the documentation already, and used merge and saveorupdate as well but still have the same problem.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296007/tool-to-campare-two-hibernate-objects-of-a-table-in-struts2-application/17296150#17296150

Comment: @Rey thanks rey does that mean I should set the id and merge and saveorUpdate does not do it automatically ?

Answer (score 7):

> *although the row exists it creates a new one*

That's not quite right.  It's not just hibernate automatically deciding to create a new user.  Hibernate is doing what your code tells it to:

- In `addMyUsers()`, you create `new Name()` and `new User()`, and you give neither of these a pre-existing ID.  You have made these objects look like new ones, rather than pre-existing ones to be updated.
- In `addMyUser()`, you call `session.merge(user)`.  Hibernate sees the objects have no ID - so it merges them and assigns them the NEW status.  When the transaction is flushed & committed, hibernate generates SQL to create new IDs and store the objects as new records.

If you want to determine whether an object is pre-existing, and operate on the previous record where possible:

1. Obtain the fields that you want to use (e.g. from a web form) - in your case, this includes "det" field.
2. See if the record already exists in the database.  Retrieve the object using hibernate via `session.find()` or `session.get()`, in your case using the "det" field.
3. If the object cannot be found, *then* create a new object.
4. For retrieved objects, you can optionally detach the object from the session before modification, (e.g. via `session.clear()`).  Newly created objects are already in a detached state.
5. Modify the object (set it's fields).
6. If the object is detached, then attach via `session.merge()`.  Merge works for both pre-existing detached objects (obtained via retrieval) and new detached objects (via `new <Object>()`).  Alternatively, for pre-existing detached objects you can call `session.update()` and for new detached objects you can call `session.save()/persist()`.
7. flush/commit the transaction.

You're missing (2).

Comment: NP.  I have answered your bold part.  You can't get an ID out of "thin air".  You must retrieve it (step 2).

Comment: @GlenBest Thanks for your answer but I have another problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396586/how-to-prevent-hibernate-of-changing-fileds-to-null

Answer (score 4):

Its primary key that plays important role here. you should use name as primary key in this case but i will not suggest you to do that, take id as primary key.

Update:

Also in case of update id should be same with the record you want to update, but in case of insertion, id should be null and you will get it inserted in db.

Answer to your comments :

you need to fetch the primary key and track it this way:

```
   session.update(recordEntity);// or save 
   int id=recordEntity.getId();
```

Answer (score 2):

you must get the **Name** first, not **new Name()**.

so use menu like "search user"/dropdown or something for user to choose the **Name** they want, then you can add that **Name** to **new User.name**

or if you dont want to search for Name first(from the thin air#lol), you should not use **User.name** with the type of **Name** in the first place, use **string** then. but it's more risky. and the relationship cant be build that way(you must query again if you want to get **Name** from the **User** that have name x).

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured this way. Please share ur code if its not this way.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example", catalog = "example_catalog")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
```