# How to save postal address and address that are similar using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to upload addresses for a user. User has two addresses , address and postal address,
if these addresses are different to each other it is easy I will save both addresses but how to keep the ids the same if the addresses are the same ?

User class

```
private Address address;
private Address postalAddress;
....
```

Code

```
 ....
 session.save(user.getAddress());
 session.save(user.getPostalAddress());
 .....
```

What to do if both addresses are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to care about if these addresses are the same or not. Once you save an entity by using `session.save()`, that entity becomes managed. So the second `save()` won't do anything if the entity has already been saved.

**EDIT**:

```
Address addr = new Address();
user.setAddress(addr);
user.setPostalAddress(addr);
```

I am setting the same address to both `address` and `postalAddress`. Then if you do this:

```
session.save(user.getAddress());
session.save(user.getPostalAddress());
```

**or** do this (after defining `cascade="persist"` on the association):

```
session.save(user);
```

then Hibernate will insert only one row to `address` table and set the same id to `user.address` and `user.postalAddress` columns.

Comment: does that mean I should just use session.save(user) ?

Comment: That is different from the original question. You can do `session.save(user)`, but that won't save the addresses if you didn't define `cascade="persist"` on the association.

Comment: I am still on same question, I just do not get what you mean

Comment: The code in your original question will work, whether the `address` and `postalAddress` are the same or not. If you want to use just `session.save(user)`, you have to define a cascading persist operation. Take a look at here for an example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/

Comment: It works but I do not what to save two different rows if addresses (address and postal ) are the SAME if they are the same need to save only one row and have a single foreign key in both address and postaladdress fileds in user table.

Comment: got you now please have a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080864/how-to-avoid-creating-a-new-row-if-similar-row-exists