# Hibernate saveOrUpdate command changes fields of existing row to NULL

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have an object as member of another object, lets say Object1 and Object 2.
Object 2 is in Object 1, and has 3 fields.

I receive the details of Object 1 from user.
Also ID and name of object 2 from user and need to save the Object1 in the DB so I use 
session.saveOrUpdate(object1),

**but** it saves object1 and keep the fileds of object 2 that user provided and change the other fileds to NULL.

Should I pass all the fileds of Object2 avoid this problem or is there a way of preventing hibernate of changing those fields to NULL and keep their values ?

```
Object1

 ID
 name
 @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 Object2

Object2

  ID 
  name
  age
```

**Example**

*What I have in DB*

Object2 has ID =13 name=XYZ age=32

*User enters*

Object1 name = Jack

Object2 ID = 13 name=XYZ

*After saving object1, the object2 will be as following*

Object2 ID = 13 name=XYZ age=NULL

Comment: For update, you should read from db first,  then apply ypur changes and then save

Comment: @WandMaker question is updated

Comment: Is Object2 and embedded object or is it an association (foreign key in database)? If it's an association, what cascading is set on the relationship?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh its foreign key is in the object 1 table, question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (a) If Object1 already exists in DB, then retrieve it:

   ```
   Object1 obj1 = session.find(...);
   ```

   (b) else, if Object1 is new then create it:

   ```
   Object1 obj1 = new Object1();
   ```
2. Populate obj1 fields, by calling setter methods
3. (a) If Object2 already exists in DB, then load it:

   ```
   Object2 obj2 = obj1.getObject2();  // ensures object2 loaded; 
                                      // does lazy load if required (e.g. one-to-many)
   ```

   (b) else, if Object2 is new then create it, and attach it to Object1:

   ```
   Object2 obj2 = new Object2();
   obj1.setObject2(obj2);
   ```
4. Populate obj2 fields, by calling setter methods
5. If Object1 to Object2 relationship has Cascade UPDATE OR ALL:

   ```
   session.saveOrUpdate(obj1);
   ```

**You're not doing (3a)** (or you're doing (3a), but then replacing it with (3b)).

Comment: does that mean once user enters the information for object 2 I have to retrieve all of its values to solve the problem?

Comment: Of course.  You always retrieve all values of a JPA entity.  Never partial.  It usually makes very little difference at all to performance.  The main performance hit is in selecting the right rows.  Once rows found, less impact to retrieve columns.  In extreme cases, if you have many dozens or 100s of columns in a table - (*cough*) bad design (*cough*) - then you can split into two tables with one-to-one relationship (good), or you can use lots of lazy loaded columns (poor/minimize).